# How to show/hide password in TextFormField?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Currently I have my password `TextFormField` like this:

```dart
TextFormField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
      labelText: 'Password',
      icon: const Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
        child: const Icon(Icons.lock),
      )),
  validator: (val) => val.length < 6 ? 'Password too short.' : null,
  onSaved: (val) => _password = val,
  obscureText: true,
);
```

I want a button like interaction which will make password visible and invisible. Can I do it inside `TextFormField`? Or I will have to make a `Stack` widget to get my required UI. And how will the condition be made regarding `obscureText` true/false?

Comment: Just make `true` that you pass to `obscureText` a variable and toggle it, for example in a function you pass to `onPressed: if a button

Answer (score 146, accepted):

First make you widget `StatefulWidget` if it is a `StatelessWidget`.

Then have a variable `bool _obscureText` and pass it to your `TextFormField`. The toggle it with `setState` as required.

Example:

```
class _FormFieldSampleState extends State<FormFieldSample> {

  // Initially password is obscure
  bool _obscureText = true;

  String _password;

  // Toggles the password show status
  void _toggle() {
    setState(() {
      _obscureText = !_obscureText;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Sample"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  icon: const Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                      child: const Icon(Icons.lock))),
              validator: (val) => val.length < 6 ? 'Password too short.' : null,
              onSaved: (val) => _password = val,
              obscureText: _obscureText,
            ),
            new FlatButton(
                onPressed: _toggle,
                child: new Text(_obscureText ? "Show" : "Hide"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used Stack instead of container. So the password overlaps with the button. I put padding inside FlatButton container. Still overlapping. Any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: But why stack? Try `Row` for horizontal arrangement and `Column` for vertical arrangement

Comment: Here's how the design will be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8aQU.png
Instead of the icon it will be the FlatButton. As because it's top of the TextFormField I used Stack.

Comment: There is no need of Stack. `InputDecoration` has a [`suffixIcon`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InputDecoration/suffixIcon.html) property which might be what you are looking for exactly.

Comment: Seems Stack is still needed for Cupertino?  suffixIcon appears to only work for Material.

Comment: Yes, we can use suffixIcon attribute of InputDecoration for TextFormField eg. decoration: InputDecoration(
                          suffixIcon: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon((_isPasswordVisible) ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off),
                            onPressed: (){

                            },
                          ),)

Answer (score 306):

I have created a solution as per @Hemanth Raj but in a more robust way.

First declare a `bool` variable `_passwordVisible`.

Initiate `_passwordVisible` to `false` in `initState()`

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _passwordVisible = false;
  }
```

Following is the `TextFormField` widget :

```
TextFormField(
   keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
   controller: _userPasswordController,
   obscureText: !_passwordVisible,//This will obscure text dynamically
   decoration: InputDecoration(
       labelText: 'Password',
       hintText: 'Enter your password',
       // Here is key idea
       suffixIcon: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              // Based on passwordVisible state choose the icon
               _passwordVisible
               ? Icons.visibility
               : Icons.visibility_off,
               color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
               ),
            onPressed: () {
               // Update the state i.e. toogle the state of passwordVisible variable
               setState(() {
                   _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
               });
             },
            ),
          ),
        );
```

Comment: in the default Normal cases, on page load password is obscured so would initiate passwordVisible  as true i.e ```passwordVisible= true``` , and to make it make sense in this case replace variable ```passwordVisible``` with ```passwordObscured= true```

Comment: Adding to what nelson pointed out, a simple fix to this is doing 
`obscureText: !passwordVisible`

Comment: thanks this worked for me..! but the validator is not working

Comment: Nice and easy, thanks for this! Also to note: doesn't have to be a Stateful widget, can be Stateless and have it rebuilt from a Stateful screen widget.

Answer (score 24):

This solution prevents taps in the suffixIcon from giving focus to the TextField, but if the TextField was focused and user wants to reveal/hide the password, then focus is not lost.

[image: Result]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PasswordField extends StatefulWidget {
  const PasswordField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PasswordFieldState createState() => _PasswordFieldState();
}

class _PasswordFieldState extends State<PasswordField> {
  final textFieldFocusNode = FocusNode();
  bool _obscured = false;

  void _toggleObscured() {
    setState(() {
      _obscured = !_obscured;
      if (textFieldFocusNode.hasPrimaryFocus) return; // If focus is on text field, dont unfocus
      textFieldFocusNode.canRequestFocus = false;     // Prevents focus if tap on eye
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
      obscureText: _obscured,
      focusNode: textFieldFocusNode,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never, //Hides label on focus or if filled
        labelText: "Password",
        filled: true, // Needed for adding a fill color
        fillColor: Colors.grey.shade800, 
        isDense: true,  // Reduces height a bit
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,              // No border
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),  // Apply corner radius
        ),
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_rounded, size: 24),
        suffixIcon: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 4, 0),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: _toggleObscured,
            child: Icon(
              _obscured
                  ? Icons.visibility_rounded
                  : Icons.visibility_off_rounded,
              size: 24,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution. Nevertheless instead of using GestureDetector and Icon, you could use IconButton.

Comment: Yes, the thing is I don’t like the ink effect of IconButton and I know now you can disable it with splash/highlight color properties but I didn’t know that back when I posted this.

Answer (score 18):

With a credit goes to [X-Wei](https://github.com/X-Wei/flutter_catalog), you can create the widget as a separate `password.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PasswordField extends StatefulWidget {
  const PasswordField({
    this.fieldKey,
    this.hintText,
    this.labelText,
    this.helperText,
    this.onSaved,
    this.validator,
    this.onFieldSubmitted,
  });

  final Key fieldKey;
  final String hintText;
  final String labelText;
  final String helperText;
  final FormFieldSetter<String> onSaved;
  final FormFieldValidator<String> validator;
  final ValueChanged<String> onFieldSubmitted;

  @override
  _PasswordFieldState createState() => new _PasswordFieldState();
}

class _PasswordFieldState extends State<PasswordField> {
  bool _obscureText = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new TextFormField(
      key: widget.fieldKey,
      obscureText: _obscureText,
      maxLength: 8,
      onSaved: widget.onSaved,
      validator: widget.validator,
      onFieldSubmitted: widget.onFieldSubmitted,
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
        border: const UnderlineInputBorder(),
        filled: true,
        hintText: widget.hintText,
        labelText: widget.labelText,
        helperText: widget.helperText,
        suffixIcon: new GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _obscureText = !_obscureText;
            });
          },
          child:
          new Icon(_obscureText ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Call it as:

```
  import 'package:my_app/password.dart';

  String _password;
  final _passwordFieldKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState<String>>();

  PasswordField(
    fieldKey: _passwordFieldKey,
    helperText: 'No more than 8 characters.',
    labelText: 'Password *',
    onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
      setState(() {
        this._password = value;
      });
    },
  ),
```

Answer (score 14):

Well I personally like to keep the passwords hidden all the time and seen when you want to see them, so this is the approach I use to hide/unhide passwords,Incase you want the password to be visible when the touch is In contact with the hide icon, and hidden as soon as you remove the contact then this is for you

```
//make it invisible globally
  bool invisible = true;

//wrap your toggle icon in Gesture Detector
  GestureDetector(
   onTapDown: inContact,//call this method when incontact
   onTapUp: outContact,//call this method when contact with screen is removed
   child: Icon(
   Icons.remove_red_eye,
   color: colorButton,
   ),
  ),

  void inContact(TapDownDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      invisible = false;
    });
  }

  void outContact(TapUpDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      invisible=true;
    });
  }
```

This approach is being used in of my packages
https://pub.dev/packages/passwordfield

The output of the above code

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I did it with holding and releasing the longTap:

```
    bool _passwordVisible;

@override
void initState() {
    _passwordVisible = false;
    super.initState();
}

// ...
TextFormField(
  obscureText: !_passwordVisible,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hasFloatingPlaceholder: true,
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
    labelText: "Password",
    suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: () {
        setState(() {
          _passwordVisible = true;
        });
      },
      onLongPressUp: () {
        setState(() {
          _passwordVisible = false;
        });
      },
      child: Icon(
          _passwordVisible ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off),
    ),
  ),
  validator: (String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return "*Password needed";
    }
  },
  onSaved: (String value) {
    _setPassword(value);
  },
);
```

Answer (score 11):

---

○     Just a Simple 3 Steps you can follow and password Show/Hide done.

---

[image]

Step 1:create variable

```
       bool _isHidden = true;
```

Step 2: Magical Step, make the icon clickable and see/hide the password.

Now I will wrap the icon with InkWell which will make it clickable. So, when we will click on that it will toggle the obscureText the argument between true and false.

```
 @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
          body: Center(
            child: Container(
            height: 55,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
            child: TextField(
              obscureText: _isHidden,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Password',
                suffix: InkWell(
                  onTap: _togglePasswordView,  /// This is Magical Function
                  child: Icon(
                    _isHidden ?         /// CHeck Show & Hide.
                     Icons.visibility :
                     Icons.visibility_off,
                  ),
                ),
                /*icon: Icon(
                  Icons.password_sharp,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),*/
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
     );
  }
```

Step 3: Create This the Magical Function.

```
      void _togglePasswordView() {
    setState(() {
        _isHidden = !_isHidden;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {

        // Initially password is obscure
  bool _obscureText = true;
    // Toggles the password show status
  void _togglePasswordStatus() {
    setState(() {
      _obscureText = !_obscureText;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
    Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text('Sign In'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:20.0,horizontal:50.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Password',
                suffixIcon:  IconButton(
                  icon:Icon(_obscureText ? Icons.visibility:Icons.visibility_off,),
                   onPressed: _togglePasswordStatus,
                   color: Colors.pink[400],
                   ),
              ),
              validator: (val){
                return
                val.length < 6 ? 'Enter A Password Longer Than 6 Charchters' :null;
              },
              obscureText: _obscureText,
              onChanged: (val){
                setState(() {
                  password = val.trim();
                });
              },
            ),
        ],),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer could use a bit more context.  Explain what it does and how it improves upon previous answers.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simpler example with built-in material design icons:

```
child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  fillColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF), filled: true,
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF808080)),
                  ),
                  suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _showPassword = !_showPassword;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                        _showPassword ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
                    ),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Password'),
              obscureText: !_showPassword,
            ),
```

Answer (score 3):

```dart
  bool _obscuredText = true; 

  _toggle(){
    setState(() {
      _obscuredText = !_obscuredText;
    });
  }

  Widget _createPassword(){
    return TextField(
      obscureText: _obscuredText,
      cursorColor: Colors.black54,
      style: TextStyle( color: Colors.black54),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black54
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.black54
            )
        ),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
        ),
        labelText: 'Contraseña',
        hintText: 'Contraseña',
        suffixIcon: FlatButton(onPressed: _toggle, child:Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye, color: _obscuredText ? Colors.black12 : Colors.black54))
      ),
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _password = value;
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
//Password
const TextField(
  obscureText: true, //for hide Password
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_outline),
      hintText: 'Password'),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my Widget with Getx

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
RxBool  passwordVisible = false.obs;
return
  Obx(() => TextFormField(
    obscureText: !passwordVisible.value,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
        suffixIcon: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          passwordVisible.value
              ? Icons.visibility
              : Icons.visibility_off,
          color: Colors.black,
          size: 20,
        ),
          onPressed: (){
            passwordVisible.value = !passwordVisible.value;
          },
      ),
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        filled: true,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ), ),
  ));}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a customizable textformfield widget I made:

```dart
// curstom_text_form_field.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomTextFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? label;
  final String? hint;
  final String? errorMessage;
  bool obscureText;
  final bool hasObscuredText;
  final TextInputType? keyboardType;
  final Function(String)? onChanged;
  final Function(String)? onFieldSubmitted;
  final String? Function(String?)? validator;
  final TextEditingController? controller;

  CustomTextFormField({
    super.key,
    this.label,
    this.hint,
    this.errorMessage,
    this.obscureText = false,
    this.hasObscuredText = false,
    this.keyboardType = TextInputType.text,
    this.onChanged,
    this.onFieldSubmitted,
    this.validator,
    this.controller,
  });

  @override
  State<CustomTextFormField> createState() => _CustomTextFormFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFormFieldState extends State<CustomTextFormField> {
  void _togglePasswordView() {
    setState(() {
      widget.obscureText = !widget.obscureText;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final border = OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40));

    return TextFormField(
      controller: widget.controller,
      readOnly: false,
      onChanged: widget.onChanged,
      validator: widget.validator,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: border,
        isDense: true,
        label: widget.label != null ? Text(widget.label!) : null,
        hintText: widget.hint,
        errorText: widget.errorMessage,
        suffixIcon: widget.hasObscuredText
            ? Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: _togglePasswordView,
                    icon: Icon(
                      widget.obscureText
                          ? Icons.visibility
                          : Icons.visibility_off,
                    )),
              )
            : null,
      ),
      obscureText: widget.obscureText,
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank @Parikshit Chalke for answer. However,
`setState` is quite expensive call if your only want to update your `TextFormField` and `IconButton`. Instead, wrap it inside [StatefulBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html) and have only child items updated.

Example solution:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  // initially password is invisible
  bool _passwordVisible = false;
  String _password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        // other widget that does not need update when password visibility is toggled
        Text("I do not require update"),
        
        StatefulBuilder(builder: (_context, _setState) {
          // only following widget gets update when _setState is used
          return TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  _passwordVisible ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  // use _setState that belong to StatefulBuilder
                  _setState(() {
                    _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
                  });
                },
              ),
              labelText: 'Password',
              icon: const Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                child: const Icon(Icons.lock),
              ),
            ),
            validator: (val) => val.length < 6 ? 'Password too short.' : null,
            onSaved: (val) => _password = val,
            obscureText: true,
          );
        }),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have more useful solution. You can use Provider and listen TextFormField with Consumer Widget**

**obscure_text_state.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ObscureTextState with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isTrue = true;
  bool get isTrue => _isTrue;

  get switchObsIcon {
    return _isTrue ? Icon(Icons.visibility_off) : Icon(Icons.visibility);
  }

  void toggleObs() {
    _isTrue = !_isTrue;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**Then you should listen that state with Consumer where TextFromField is.**

```
            Consumer<ObscureTextState>(
              builder: (context, obs, child) {
                return TextFormField(
                  controller: _passwordController,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return "Alan boş bırakılamaz!";
                    } else if (value.length < 6) {
                      return "Şifre en az 6 haneden oluşmalıdır.";
                    } else {
                      return null;
                    }
                  },
                  obscureText:
                      Provider.of<ObscureTextState>(context, listen: false)
                          .isTrue,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Provider.of<ObscureTextState>(context, listen: false)
                              .toggleObs();
                        },
                        icon: Provider.of<ObscureTextState>(context,
                                listen: false)
                            .switchObsIcon,
                      ),
                      hintText: "Şifre",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0))),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score -1):

````
    TextFormFeild(
    decoration:InputDecoration(
     icon: _isSecurityIcon == true
  ? IconButton(
   icon: Icon(Icons.visibility_off_outlined),
onPressed: () {
   setState(() {
_isSecurityIcon = false;
   });
  },
)
: IconButton(
icon: Icon(Icons.visibility_outlined),
onPressed: () {
setState(
() {
_isSecurityIcon = true;
    },
    );
    },
   ),
   ),
  );```
````