# Prevent focusing of TextFormField when I tap suffixIcon inside the TextFormField

Tags: flutter

When I press the button and the TextFormField will be focused and the keyboard will appear. How to fix this problem?
code below:

```
TextFormField(
              controller: code,
              focusNode: codeFocus,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'verify code',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.sms),
                suffixIcon: FlatButton(
                  onPressed:(){}
                  child: Text('send sms'),
                  textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
                ),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            ),
            focusNode: codeFocus,
          )
```

Comment: I had the same problem for the common password's eye for visibility. I want suffixIcon taps not to focus the text field but I also don't want focus to be lost if user is typing the password and toggles visibility. Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125064/how-to-show-hide-password-in-textformfield/68910940#68910940

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use stack like this.

```
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
  children: <Widget>[
    TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'verify code',
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.sms),
      ),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    ),
    FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
      child: Text('send sms'),
    ),
  ],
)
```

[The same question was asked few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58097067/clickable-icon-on-textformfield-disable-textformfield-focus-on-icon-click-flu/58221090) by the way...

Answer (score 2):

### Use this function when you tap on your suffixIcon.

```
() {
  // This will help to wait for TextField to get focus before
  // we unfocus but it will happen fast so that you won't notice.
  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
    _yourInputFocusNode.unfocus();
    // Your implementation to run when tap suffixIcon in TextField
  });
},
```

### Example

```
TextFormField(
  focusNode: _phoneNumberFocusNode,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.contacts),
      onPressed: () {
        Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
          _phoneNumberTwoFocusNode.unfocus();
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'Contacts');
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
),
```