# why show/hide password not working when use stack widget in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, passwords, togglebutton

why show/hide password not working when use stack widget in flutter

class FormData extends StatefulWidget{

@override
FormDataState  createState()  => FormDataState();

}

class FormDataState extends State{

final formKey = GlobalKey();

TextEditingController _accidentCtrl = TextEditingController();

TextEditingController _passCtrl = TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
final Formlist formProvider = Provider.of<Formlist>(context);
bool _isObscure = true;
```

Stack(

```
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 360,
                    height: 96,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xffFAFAFA),

                    ),),
                ),


Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, right: 25, left: 25),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 44,
                            width: 315,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xffF2F3F5),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            child:TextField(
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12, bottom: 10, left: 10),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                      _isObscure ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _isObscure = !_isObscure;
                                    });
                                  }),
                          ),

                          obscureText: _isObscure,
                          controller: _passCtrl,
                      
                        ),
```

please help me, is it code true or any mistake?
i used stack because make this input with container like card.

Comment: Could you provide more code of the widget where you use this `TextField`, or at least the code that shows where you store/initialize the `_isObscure` variable?

Comment: sorry, the question already edited

Comment: bool _isObscure = true;

TextEditingController _passCtrl = TextEditingController();

Comment: Where did you place these variables? One thing that could cause your problem is placing these variables in the `Widget build()` method. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67664586/changing-visibility-of-a-a-button-clear-textformfield/67664668#67664668

Comment: ohh sorry, please look my edited question

Comment: thank you @kforjan for the link, my question solved

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer

put the variable `_isObscure` in class `FormDataState extends State{}`
not put the variable in `@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {}`