# How to center the string in text widget

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CgsY.png)

How can i center my text "......" like this, thanks. Align or center widget or textAlign is not working, please help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp3Kz.png)

```
      Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.visibility_off_outlined,
                                    color: Colors.black
                                        .withOpacity(0.25),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    "..........",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xFF0E5699),
                                      fontSize: 32,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
```

Vertically center this text like an icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine and already vertically center. Since you use "." so the dot will be in the bottom. If you want to create a center dot. Use bullet instead
You can use `\u2022` to create a unicode bullet.

```
Text(
  "\u2022\u2022\u2022\u2022\u2022\u2022",
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Color(0xFF0E5699),
    fontSize: 32,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
  ),
),
```

But I wonder what the purpose of your question. If you trying to create a `TextField` for password input purpose you can check here [How to show/hide password in TextFormField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125064/how-to-show-hide-password-in-textformfield)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. This works for me:

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Icon(
        Icons.visibility_off_outlined,
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.25),
      ),
      Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
        child: const Text(
          "........",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF0E5699),
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```