# How to hide Show the Password in TextField In Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignUpPage> createState() => _SignUpPageState();
}

class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {

  bool oT = true;//obscure-text for password
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text("Welcome Back",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                  fontFamily: "nunito",
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
              const Text("House Hunting, Simplified",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontFamily: "nunito",
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                  color: Colors.black
                ),
              ),
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
              Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 320,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border(
                    top: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                    right: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                    bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                    left: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)
                  ),
                ),
                child: const TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person_outline_rounded,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    hintText: "Enter Your UserName",
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 320,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border(
                      top: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                      right: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                      bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                      left: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)
                  ),
                ),
                child: const TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.password_rounded,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    suffixIcon: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      child: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye_outlined,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                    hintText: "Enter Your Password",
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                  obscureText: oT,

                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Moreover error is shown in obscureText parameter.

Comment: you need to have a tap event to change the oT value true/false with setstate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show/hide password in TextFormField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125064/how-to-show-hide-password-in-textformfield)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `GestureDetector` to change the `oT` value while `suffixIcon` clicked

```
suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      oT = !oT;
    });
  },
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    child: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye_outlined,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 bool isPasswordVisible = false;



TextField(
                          cursorColor: Colors.white,
                          controller: passwordController,
                          obscureText: !isPasswordVisible,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            isDense: true,
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: .7)),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                width: .7,
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                width: .7,
                              ),
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Password',
                            hintStyle: kanitTextStyle.copyWith(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 81, 117, 141),
                              fontSize: 17.sp,
                            ),
                            suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  isPasswordVisible = !isPasswordVisible;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Icon(
                                isPasswordVisible
                                    ? Coolicons.show
                                    : Coolicons.hide,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextField` should not be `const` when you are using variables in it. This should work:

```
          TextField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.password_rounded,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              suffixIcon: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.remove_red_eye_outlined,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              hintText: "Enter Your Password",
              border: InputBorder.none,
            ),
            obscureText: oT,
          )
```